# Gurobi: Prod() in addConstrs()

Tags: python, gurobi

When I set up the constraint, the code is

```
m.addConstr(binary_var.prod(cost_con) <= budget[k])
```

`binary_var` is the variable name, `cost_con` is the coefficients of the variables. The constraint is a linear expression, like

```
cost_con[0]*binary_var[0]+cost_con[1]*binary_var[1]+cost_con[2]*binary_var[2]+....
```

**Here is the problem**.
Since the number of variables is very large, nearly 5000. So the code `binary_var.prod(cost_con)` costs a lot of time. Could you please tell me if you have some better solutions to decrease the running time?

Thanks

Comment: There are no timings or indication that this step is the costly one in your (probably) bigger surrounding problem. If you really think it's that costly, why use something based on dictionaries (my interpretation of var.prod()) at all? Use flat arrays (which will loop much faster)!

Comment: The initialization of gurobi model in python requires dictionaries, so I cannot use arrays.

Comment: That's not true. I hold my variables in numpy-arrays (which others might consider crazy; but i think it's very powerful!).

Comment: Okay. I will try. Thanks so much!

Comment: Try with python's lists. The numpy-way might be slower / is not as transparent (and follow gurobi's docs: e.g. np.sum() or sum(list) vs. gurobi's quicksum). I only use numpy for it's powerful features (indexing and co) and don't care much about performance as usually solving is the dominant cost.

Comment: My original data structure is numpy-array, so I also use this form. I compared the numpy-way and dictionry-way. Here are the codes:m = Model('trial')
x = m.addVars(50000, vtype=GRB.BINARY)
a = np.ones((1, 50000))
expr1 = []
s1 = time.clock()
for i in range(50000):
    expr1 += a[0, i]*x[i]
m.setObjective(expr1, GRB.MAXIMIZE)
e1 = time.clock()

s2 = time.clock()
c = {}
for i in range(50000):
    c[i] = 1
m.setObjective(x.prod(c), GRB.MAXIMIZE)
e2 = time.clock()

The numpy-way cost 2.2s, and the dictionary way cost 0.132s. I'm not sure if you are using the numpy-way as I am.

Comment: The Gurobi documentation for `quicksum()` contains suggestions for much faster approaches to build an expression. [Check it out](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/py_quicksum.html)